# How can I keep a user field from coming through on a Journal Entry release function?

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Journal Transactions screen where I've added a user field to the grid (GLTran).  When the Release function is initiated, it adds lines as it should - but it populates the user field with the values I had in the original lines, and I don't want this to happen.  How can I intercept this process (I've looked at the source code and I can't see any functions I can use) to prevent this from happening?

I've tried the RowInserting / RowInserted events to set the field to null or blank, but this does nothing.

Thanks much -

Comment: How do you populate the user fields now?  They don't populate themselves unless you add attributes to the DAC field or through code in a graph

Comment: Read my post more thoroughly.  The user field gets populated manually, originally.  When you hit the release, it adds lines, but tries to populate the user fields with what was in the original lines, automatically.  I don't want it to do that.

Comment: My guess the user fields has some type of default value or you are using PXCache copy to create the new rows which will copy all values from the copied row. Can you include some code around the user field and its attribute and also how you are inserting the rows?

Comment: Brendan - I'm not doing anything in code to add the rows on release, and the user field I added has no default value.  The additional rows added on release is happening in Acumatica's code - which is why I want to try to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Acumatica support - an override of the Release process needs to be added to the Journal Entry BLC extension code, adding Event handlers as follows:

```
    public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<PostGraph>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowPersisting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
            {
                var gltran = e.Row as GLTran;
                if (gltran != null)
                {
                    var gltranext = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(gltran);
                    gltranext.UsrProject = null;
                }
            });
        });

        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
```

Thanks much, Cesar!